What is the shortcut key for Repeat History?
Is there a shortcut for the Repeat History option within the Edit menu?

I cannot find this in Edit > Preferences > Keymap.
Tried with Blender 3.4 and Blender 4.1
I think in other versions it was F3, but now is designated as the search function.

You can right-click on the menu entry and choose Assign Shortcut, then you are asked to press a key. This does not have to be a single key, it can be combined with Ctrl, Shift, Alt as well. After you did that it will be found and editable in the keymap.

You can set your own .. (right-click on the menu item) or add it to your quick favourites.. would either of those be OK?

Oh, thank you !

By the way, F3 has been Repeat History until 2.79, since 2.8 it was used for the search function, just for information.
